# What type of flower is this?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

I have collected this flower for a task but am not able to find its name. Which flower is this?

Comment: Off a tree, woody shrub or low growing plant? What part of the world and what were the leaves like?

Comment: A photo of the entire plant would be very helpful! 